# How assign delete key to nautilus script in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, 20.04, nautilus-script

I want to assign Delete key to my script.
It works when I add to scripts-accels:

```
<Primary>Delete myScript.sh
```

but

```
Delete myScript.sh
```

keeps default behavior (move to trash) and ignores my script.
Any ideas? (btw. It was possible in older distros - shortcut in accels file worked, but accels file is not used anymore)

Answer (score 1):

`scripts-accels` does still work (fortunately), as you noted yourself. However, it will not allow you to override shortcuts that are already defined in the application (as you also noted). You will need to work around by using a different keyboard combinations not already used by nautilus.

This answer will be disappointing, and I would be very happy to see an answer appear that indicates how to do it. However, to my knowledge, it is not possible without editing source code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System settings > Keyboard shortcuts > Add your own shortcut

Name it whatever you want, and in the command, use `use /full/path/to/script.sh`. Set the shortcut key to the delete key.

Comment: I want to run script before moving file to trash. Your solution would lock Delete key globally. Is it possible in bash script to pass delete key forward unless active window is nautilus?